# Request header parameters

Tags: request-headers

What are the use of the below parameters in request headers.

```
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Keep-Alive  115
Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
Cache-Control   max-age=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all specified in detail in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).